# Having problems to test an AngularJS service that returns a promise

Tags: angularjs

I can't make this test work. The service (mqttService) returns

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {

    var client;

    function onConnected() {
      var message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(payload);
      message.destinationName = sendConfig.destination;
      client.subscribe(sendConfig.subscribe);
      client.send(message);
    }

    function onMessageArrived(message) {
      resolve(message.payloadString);
    }

    function onFailure() {
      reject({
        message: "can't connect"
      });
    }

    function onConnectionLost() {
      reject({
        message: "connection lost"
      });
    }

    client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(config.getMqttConfig().host,
      config.getMqttConfig().port,
      sendConfig.clientId);

    client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

    client.connect({
      onSuccess: onConnected,
      onFailure: onFailure
    });


  });
```

The purpose of this service is to connect to an MQTT server and return a value from a subscription.

I verified that the client.connect is called but I can't even see a connect attempt in the server logs.

I know that I can mock things but I wan't an integration test.

This is how the test looks right now:

```
describe('Mqtt Service Unit Tests', function() {
  var mqttService, rootscope;
  beforeEach(module('starter.factories'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_mqttService_, $rootScope) {
    mqttService = _mqttService_;
    rootScope =  $rootScope;
  }));

  it('can call service', inject(function(mqttService) {

    expect(mqttService).toBeDefined();

    var result = mqttService.send("{'id': hello}", {
      subscribe: 'mydata/test',
      destination: 'mydata/test',
      clientId: '12345'
    });

    rootScope.$digest();

    result.then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });

   expect(1).toEqual(1);

  }));

});
```

Comment: The problem is that the current 1.9.x PhantomJS release does not support websockets. Therefore no problem with Angular.

Comment: Yes I'm doing that now